# REST API to create subsite in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint

Could anyone help me in letting me know how to create subsite in Sharepoint 2010 using REST api ? Unable to find any help .

Basically i have to do integration with SharePoint 2010 from my UI application using angular js . But before that i wanted to try it in the rest client on to see what things to pass to create a subsite.

Regards,
Nischal

Comment: check this article by marc : http://sympmarc.com/2014/03/30/create-a-subsite-in-sharepoint-2013-using-rest-calls/

Comment: @Vaibhav- I am looking to create in Sharepoint 2010 . The article which you share seems like is applicable to Sharepoint 2013 . Can you please share for 2010 ?

Answer (score 0):

public subsite_create(requestdata: SubsiteModels) {

```
    let requestdatastr: string = JSON.stringify(
        {
            'parameters': {
                '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.WebInfoCreationInformation' },
                'Title': requestdata.Title,
                'Description': requestdata.Description,
                'Language': 1033,
                'WebTemplate': 'STS#0',
                'Url': requestdata.Url,
                'UseUniquePermissions': requestdata.UseUniquePermissions
            }
        });
    console.log("Response:", requestdatastr);
    this.context.spHttpClient.post(`${this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/web/webinfos/add`,
        SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
        {
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
                'Content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
                'odata-version': ''
            },
            body: requestdatastr
        })
        .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
            response.json().then((responseJSON: JSON) => {
                console.log(responseJSON);
            });


        });
}
```

The above code which is helpful1 you to create subsites.
Rest API for subsite creation is mentioned below

```
    this.context.spHttpClient.post(`${this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/web/webinfos/add`,
```

It works for me, hope it works to you.

Comment: Consider adding an explanation of how the code you posted works. Additionally, I'm no expert, but the second snippet seems to end prematurely; please make sure it's complete and syntactically correct.

Comment: The second snippet which is the api for create subsite in your tenant.

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-retrieve-update-or-delete-sites-on-sharepoint-using-rest-api/

Comment: The above link, explained briefly about how to create subsite briefly.

Comment: __metadata': { 'type': 'SP.WebInfoCreationInformation' }, which helps to createthe subsite.  'Title': requestdata.Title,
                'Description': requestdata.Description,
                'Language': 1033,
                'WebTemplate': 'STS#0',
                'Url': requestdata.Url,
                'UseUniquePermissions': requestdata.UseUniquePermissions, The above are the data which given for the subsite to create.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below code.

This will help you to create sharepoint subsite with **REST API** and **HttpClient**

```js
using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(webUri);
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-RequestDigest", formDigest);

                    var json = string.Format("{{'parameters':{{'__metadata': {{'type': 'SP.WebInfoCreationInformation'}}, 'Url':'{0}','Title':'{0}','Description':'Sito per la pratica {0}','Language':1033,'WebTemplate':'sts','UseUniquePermissions':false}}}}",nameSubsite);
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ContentLength", json.Length.ToString());
                    HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(json);

                    httpContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json;odata=verbose");
                    httpContent.Headers.ContentType.Parameters.Add(new NameValueHeaderValue("odata", "verbose"));


                    var getAsyncTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    {
                        HttpResponseMessage result = client.PostAsync("/_api/web/webinfos/add", httpContent).Result;
                        return result;

                    });
                    response = getAsyncTask.Result;
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                }
```